Supabase email confirmation to website and then open app
I have my app built using React Native (Expo), BaaS Supabase and my website using NextJS. I'm having some issues figuring out how to redirect the user to my app and keep him on the website if it doesnt have the app installed on the phone (I dont even know if thats possible to validate), but this is the expected output:
Supabase URL configurations:
Site URL:

https://mywebsite.com

Redirect URLs:

com.appbundle://

com.appbundle://**

com.appbundle


Supabase Email Template
{{ .SiteURL }}/en/emailConfirmation?token_hash={{ .TokenHash }}&type=signup&redirect_to={{ .RedirectTo }}

React Native Supabase sign up
const redirectUrl = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
  scheme: ResourceStrings.appScheme,
});
const {
      data: { session },
      error,
    } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email,
      password,
      options: {
        data: {
          username,
          email,
        },
        emailRedirectTo: redirectUrl,
      },
    });

The expected output is the image below:

